# How to recieve socket.io message from node.js server to android client

Tags: android, socket.io, kotlin

I have an application that in server side we configured a socket.IO for it.
and I want to connect my application to that, listening to server when an event happened ,then my application Log a message in android side.

I have a `BaseActivity` that all of my activities extends from that. and in BaseActivity I setup Socket.IO:

```
    protected var mSocket: Socket? = null       

    try {
         mSocket = IO.socket("http://myDomain.co")
    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
    }

    mSocket!!.connect()
```

then in target activity I use this code:

```
mSocket!!.on("record_create", { args ->
    this@MainPage.runOnUiThread({
        val data = args[0] as JSONObject
        Log.i("LOGGG", data.getString("record_create").toString())
    })
})
```

but nothings happened!

whats my problem?

Or

How can I do this job in best way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself:

by initializing `socket.io` in target activity, and call `socket.io` listeners in this class